# Select single ID in SQL statement with multiple criteria

Tags: sql

I want to get the post id's wich contain %planet% and %world.

With this statement I would get a single 94 as post_id.

Possible duplicate for the current question is this post: [SQL: how to select a single id ("row") that meets multiple criteria from a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179260/sql-how-to-select-a-single-id-row-that-meets-multiple-criteria-from-a-singl)

I can't seem to figure out how to use a LIKE statement.

```
post_id   Meta           Value

96        Hello World    123
96        Hello World    123
92        Hello World    123
93        Hello World    123
93        Hello World    123
94        Hello World    123
94        Hello Planet   1234
94        Hello World
95        Hello World
95        Hello World
```

Comment: What specific database are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as an answer. Answers don't go in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need. It's two queries joined. First one gets list ids containing planet. Second gets list id with world. I joined the two together meaning it  has to be in both queries to be returned.

```
select a.post_id from 
(select post_id from t1 where meta like '%planet%' group by post_id) a
join
(select post_id from t1 where meta like '%world%' group by post_id) b
on a.post_id = b.post_id
```

Comment: You need `select a.post_id`, not `a_id`. And the `1 hasValue` part is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Because the results are split across multiple records (no one record contains both `planet` and `world`, but for a single `post_id` both are found e.g. in `post_id` 94) you need a two-step approach.

Ignoring performance issues, the following will give you the expected results (SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    post_id INT,
    Meta VARCHAR(100),
    Value INT
)

 INSERT INTO @MyTable
        (post_id, Meta, Value)
 VALUES (96, 'Hello World', 123),
        (96, 'Hello World', 123),
        (92, 'Hello World', 123),
        (93, 'Hello World', 123),
        (93, 'Hello World', 123),
        (94, 'Hello World', 123),
        (94, 'Hello Planet', 1234),
        (94, 'Hello World', NULL),
        (95, 'Hello World', NULL),
        (95, 'Hello World', NULL)

 SELECT DISTINCT post_id
   FROM @MyTable
  WHERE post_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM @MyTable WHERE [Meta] LIKE '%planet%')
    AND [Meta] LIKE '%world%'
```