# How to select rows that meets multiple criteria from a single column in SQL?

Tags: sql, select

I have a question similar to this one:

[SQL: how to select a single id ("row") that meets multiple criteria from a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179260/sql-how-to-select-a-single-id-row-that-meets-multiple-criteria-from-a-singl)

But in my case, the pairs of values are not unique, for example:

A user_id could be paired with same ancestry more than one time (more than one row with same user_id - ancestry).

Which could be a good and efficient solution?

The array of ancestries that must pass the condition could be large and variable (until 200) which makes me think that the join solution will be very inefficient. Furthermore as pairs of values are not uniques, the "in..group by" solution will not works.

Comment: If you provide sample data, then it would be easier to help. Even better if you can create a sqlfiddle for this. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1

Comment: How is this question tagged under SQL **AND** MDX?

Comment: Because I want the SQL solution to implement it with MDX later. I only want the solution for the problem. Nevertheless I put MDX trying to have luck.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Do you want to know which user_id has X ancestors (X being a variable amount of ancestors)?

```
Select t.user_id
from (select distinct * 
      from your_table) t
where t.ancestry in XAncestors
group by t.user_id
having count(t.user_id) = length(XAncestors)
```

Just to clarify, this is the exact same query as in the question you posted but with a subquery in the from to select only distinct values