# Where clause in pivot-structured table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, db2, ibm-cloud

I have a table in DB2 (oracle syntax) looking like this, let's call it SAMPLE

```
ID    TAG_NAME    VALUE
13    10          77
13    11          80
14    10          92
14    11          83
```

What I want to do is select all rows where TAG_NAME 10 has VALUE 77 and TAG_NAME 11 has VALUE 80. How can I do this? If I do like below it will try to create a situation where the TAG_NAME has to be both 10 and 11, while the VALUE has to be both 77 and 80. I don't want to select these specific tag names, rather when the tag name is x then it should check that the value is y etc.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    SAMPLE
WHERE
    (TAG_NAME=10 AND VALUE=77)
    AND (TAG_NAME=11 AND VALUE=80)
```

The result I want to achieve is this:

```
ID    TAG_NAME    VALUE
13    10          77
13    11          80
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: how to select a single id ("row") that meets multiple criteria from a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179260/sql-how-to-select-a-single-id-row-that-meets-multiple-criteria-from-a-singl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM SAMPLE s
WHERE (TAG_NAME = 10 AND VALUE = 77) OR
      (TAG_NAME = 11 AND VALUE = 80)
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TAG_NAME) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know DB2, but in Oracle you can do this:

```
select *
from   demo
where  (tag_name, value) in ((10,77), (11,80));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved your own question when you said:

> If I do like below it will try to create a situation where the TAG_NAME **has to be both** 10 and 11, while the VALUE has to be both 77 and 80

If you change that to OR it should work.

```
SELECT 
    * .
FROM 
    SAMPLE
WHERE
    (TAG_NAME=10 AND VALUE=77)
    OR (TAG_NAME=11 AND VALUE=80)
    OR (TAG_NAME=x AND VALUE=y)
```