# select records from same table with matching values in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a query for scenario as under:
**Ledger Table**

```
Invoice No.     Date              Amount OfficeCode  

101             01-01-2013        100.00  LONDON

102             01-02-2013        100.00  LONDON
102             04-02-2013       1100.00  LEEDS

103            11-03-2013        100.00  LONDON
103             19-04-2013        150.00  LEEDS

104            01-01-2013        100.00  LONDON
```

I need a t-sql which wil return me Invoice records for Invoice 102 and 103 only, as these invoices exists for multiple office within same table.

I tried with self-join but I am missing something which is not returning me anything.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: `103` appears in one row only. Typo?

Comment: Why record `103`?  Simple `GROUP BY` should do the trick for you though.

Comment: So you want the minimum record number for records per office? Just offices with multiple records?

Comment: Your edits are a little confusing - -can you clarify?  Why does 102 exist multiple times now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: Select rows with a column value that occurs at least N times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760335/sql-select-rows-with-a-column-value-that-occurs-at-least-n-times)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming record 103 was a typo, you can get your desired results using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT InvoiceNo
FROM Ledger
GROUP BY InvoiceNo  
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OfficeCode) > 1
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73a6d/1)

Comment: @EliAlgranti -- glad I'm not the only one confused :D

Comment: No I want invoices with multiple offices but in actual table there are more columns.  If I use above query it's returning me quite a lot volume of records

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM Ledger
WHERE InvoiceNo IN 
(
    SELECT InvoiceNo
    FROM Ledger
    GROUP BY InvoiceNo  
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```