# MySQL Return All Related Records where Count > x with Minimum Value

Tags: mysql

I'm completely new to MySQl, so forgive my lack of jargon to explain what I need to do. I'm trying to work out how to return all records where a related table has a minimum value of more than x number of times.

For example, I am tracking charitable donations for multiple charities. I want to pull a list of donors who have contributed to AT LEAST $25 to 3 DISTINCT organizations, one row for each qualifying transaction that includes * from all 3 tables.

I've tried using join with a subquery, but it's either the wrong approach or I'm just doing it wrong (v likely!).

I was trying a method I found here: [SQL: Select rows with a column value that occurs at least N times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760335/sql-select-rows-with-a-column-value-that-occurs-at-least-n-times):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM Transactions a
  JOIN (SELECT c.*
      FROM Contributor c
  GROUP BY 
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3 and Amount > 25) a.Amount ON b. = a.lname
```

Here's the diagram of the MySQL sb (using MS Access as front end):

[image]

Comment: Please post the MySQL query you attempted, you were likely on the right track. We can help you make the necessary modifications to achieve what you're going for.

Comment: Is that $25 in total to three organizations? What if the $25 is across more than 3? Or at least $25 to each of the three organizations?

Comment: Note that id in the transaction table is redundant. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @symcbean at least 3 transactions of $25 each to 3 different orgs, sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: @BaherRamzy added the method I was attempting

Comment: Could there be multiple donations by a donor to the same charity, each less than $25 but in total more than $25? Should the total qualify the donor for your desired output? Should a date range be considered?

Comment: Examples of raw data and desired output could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came up with:

Query1 - aggregates by donor and charity and filters by Amount >=25, this query handles possibility of more than one 25+ donation by donor to same charity

```
SELECT Transactions.ContributorID, Transactions.OrganizationID
FROM Transactions
WHERE (((Transactions.Amount)>=25))
GROUP BY Transactions.ContributorID, Transactions.OrganizationID;
```

Query2 - aggregates Query1 by donor and counts charities

```
SELECT Query1.ContributorID, Count(Query1.OrganizationID) AS CountOfOrganizationID
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ContributorID
HAVING (((Count(Query1.OrganizationID))>=3));
```

Query3 - displays transactions where charity count >=3 and Amount >=25

```
SELECT Contributor.Company, Organization.CharityName, Transactions.Amount
FROM Query2 INNER JOIN (Organization INNER JOIN (Contributor INNER JOIN Transactions 
ON Contributor.ID = Transactions.ContributorID) 
ON Organization.ID = Transactions.OrganizationID) ON Query2.ContributorID = Transactions.ContributorID
WHERE (((Transactions.Amount)>=24) AND ((Query2.CountOfOrganizationID)>=3));
```

All in One:

```
SELECT Contributor.Company, Organization.CharityName, Transactions.Amount
FROM
(SELECT Query1.ContributorID, Count(Query1.OrganizationID) AS CountOfOrganizationID
FROM
(SELECT Transactions.ContributorID, Transactions.OrganizationID
FROM Transactions
WHERE (((Transactions.Amount)>=25))
GROUP BY Transactions.ContributorID, Transactions.OrganizationID) AS
Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ContributorID
HAVING (((Count(Query1.OrganizationID))>=3))) AS
Query2 INNER JOIN (Organization INNER JOIN (Contributor INNER JOIN Transactions ON Contributor.ID = Transactions.ContributorID) ON Organization.ID = Transactions.OrganizationID) ON Query2.ContributorID = Transactions.ContributorID
WHERE (((Transactions.Amount)>=24) AND ((Query2.CountOfOrganizationID)>=3));
```

Comment: So is query3 run against the result of query2, which is run against the result of query1?  If so, what is this called?  I've been searching for a way to query the result set of another query, but I was looking for "nested queries" and the like and never found anything.

Comment: It's called building a query with another query as source. Might be able to nest. I use Access query builder in SQL View and copy/paste to produce nested. However, not all query solutions can be nested. But I gave it a try and the result is in my edited answer.