# SQL Query to find records that has at least 2 male and 2 female children

Tags: sql, self-join

In an interview, I was asked to find out the names of parents who have at least **one child of each gender** i.e. **at least 1 male and 1 female**. I solved that. Then they modified the question to find names of parents who have **at least 2 male and 2 female** children. This is the table:
[Table Name: Children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDqjz.png)

Here's the query that I used for the first ask:

```
SELECT distinct C1.Parent_Name 
FROM Children C1 
JOIN Children C2
  ON C1.Parent_Name = C2.Parent_Name
WHERE C1.Child_Gender = 'Male' AND C2.Child_Gender = 'Female';
```

Can you please help with the query for the second ask?

Comment: you can order by desc limit 2 then select the last record

Comment: Most people here want sample data (and expected result) as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. PS I just googled 'SQL Query to find records that has at least 2' from your title for multiple hits--because people don't google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Select rows with a column value that occurs at least N times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760335/sql-select-rows-with-a-column-value-that-occurs-at-least-n-times)

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use condition aggregate function in `HAVING`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Parent_Name VARCHAR(50),
  Child_Gender varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES('David','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('Emma','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('David','Female');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('David','Female');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('Tom','Female');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('N','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('A','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('K','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('David','Female');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('Emma','Female');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('Emma','Female');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('Emma',null);
INSERT INTO T VALUES('J','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('D','Male');
INSERT INTO T VALUES('Emma','Male');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
Select
    Parent_Name
From Children  
GROUP BY
    Parent_Name
HAVING  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Child_Gender='Male' THEN 1 END)>1
AND 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Child_Gender='Female' THEN 1 END) > 1;

| Parent_Name |
| ----------- |
| Emma        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jHDgJF85ajbwwKkTEc8VpH/0)

Comment: I think it should be SUM instead of count

Comment: @Super.Sam did you try using SUM instead of COUNT in having?

Comment: yes, but it still gives me the parents who have one child for each gender instead of 2.

Comment: @DeepakPawar In the condition I think `SUM` and `COUNT` will get the same result, because they will add one when they hit the condition :)

Comment: @D-Shih My bad :)

Comment: @DeepakPawar That's ok!! we learn from each other that is the reason why we are here:)

Comment: @Super.Sam No problem glad to help you can mark this answer if that help you :)

Answer (score 0):

A minor change to the query only, `>= 2` instead of `>= 1` :

```
SELECT parent_Name
FROM T  
GROUP BY parent_Name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Child_Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) >= 2
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Child_Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use such solution to get not only person but also details about children.

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT PivotTable.Parent_Name, 
       PivotTable.Female As nr_of_female_children,
       PivotTable.Male As nr_of_male_children
FROM
(SELECT #T.Parent_Name, #T.Child_Gender
    FROM #T) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
COUNT(Child_Gender)
FOR Child_Gender IN (Male,Female)
) AS PivotTable

)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.nr_of_female_children>1 AND CTE.nr_of_male_children >1
```